# How to implement operator== for polymorphic classes in c++

Tags: c++

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What’s the right way to overload operator== for a class hierarchy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1691007/whats-the-right-way-to-overload-operator-for-a-class-hierarchy)

I have a base class and several derived classes like in the following code:

```
class Base
{
public:
    friend bool operator==(const Base&, const Base&);
    virtual ~Base(){}

private:
    virtual bool equals(const Base& other) const = 0;
};

bool operator==(const Base& lhs, const Base& rhs)
{
    return lhs.equals(rhs);
}

class A : public Base
{
public:
    A(int x) : x_(x){}

private:
    virtual bool equals(const Base& other) const;
    int x_;
};

bool A::equals(const Base& other) const
{
    const A* pA = dynamic_cast<const A*>(&other);
    if(!pA) return false;
    return x_ == pA->x_;
}

class B : public Base
{
public:
    B(double y) : y_(y){}

private:
    virtual bool equals(const Base& other) const;
    double y_;
};

bool B::equals(const Base& other) const
{
    const B* pB = dynamic_cast<const B*>(&other);
    if(!pB) return false;
    return y_ == pB->y_;
}
```

To be able to compare two derived classes I want to have operator==. The question is how to achieve this in an object oriented way (e.g. respecting encapsulation, maintainability and extensibility). Are there some recommended patterns to do that? Is there an alternative to the above approach avoiding dynamic_cast?

Comment: I presume you want `operator==()` to return `false` when passed one object of type `A` and one of type `B` as these classes are not directly related.  But suppose you derive a class `AA` from `A`: What do you want do you want `operator==()` to do when called with one `A` object and one `AA` object?

Comment: I think you are looking for multiple dispatch: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749534/multiple-dispatch-in-c

Comment: @j_random_hacker Two classes shall compare equal, if they have the same typeid and all member variables have equal values.

Comment: Then PiotrNycz's answer does what you want, while introducing a minimum of maintenance hassle.

Comment: @jogojapan Can you give me any hint how an implementation of `operator==()` using multiple dispatch would look like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your way is not perfect. Consider next class deriving from `A`:

```
class AA : public A
{
public:
    AA(int x, int y) : A(x), y_(y) {}

private:
    virtual bool equals(const Base& other) const;
    int y_;
};

bool AA::equals(const Base& other) const
{
    const AA* pAA = dynamic_cast<const AA*>(&other);
    if(!pAA) return false;
    return A::equals(other) && y_ == pAA->y_;
}
```

then your `operatator ==` breaks fundamental rule, it is not symmetrical relation:

```
   A a(1); 
   AA aa(1,1); 
   assert(a == aa);
   assert(!(aa == a));
```

Short fix would be to use `typeid`:

```
bool operator==(const Base& lhs, const Base& rhs)
{
    return typeid(lhs) == typeid(rhs) && lhs.equals(rhs);
}
```

Comment: +1.  Based on the fact that the `equals()` methods are private and known to only be called by `operator==()` after checking for equal dynamic types, you could change the `dynamic_cast<>` (which might take time logarithmic in the class hierarchy depth) and test for NULL to a straight `static_cast<>`.

Comment: @j_random_hacker We do not even need test for NULL, we could use `dynamic_cast<A&>` instead of `dynamic_cast<A*>`. Not sure if `static_cast<>` is safe here - what if there are multi and virtual inheritance cases?

Comment: If we know the dynamic types are exactly equal (and your test using `typeid` has established that they are) then a downcast using `static_cast<>` is guaranteed to be safe. (That's one of `static_cast<>`'s biggest uses.)