# C++: Overloads for multiple derived classes within another class

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I'm making a text based adventure game (original, I know.) and I hit a problem. I want to let the player pick up an item, and then automatically put it where it belongs based on the subclass of `Item` that it belongs to. I have it set up so that when the player types "get " followed by the name of an object in the current room, the following function is called:

```
void Game::PickUp(Item * item)
{
    m_map.at(m_player.GetLoc())->RemoveItem(item); //Remove item from the room
    m_player.AddItem(item); //Add item to the player
}
```

Within the `Player` class I've overloaded `AddItem(…)` as follows:

```
void AddItem(Armor* armor)
{
    delete m_armor;
    m_armor = armor;
}
void AddItem(Weapon* weapon)
{
    delete m_weapon;
    m_weapon = weapon;
}
void AddItem(Shield* shield)
{
    delete m_shield;
    m_shield = shield;
}
void AddItem(Item* item)
{ 
    m_pack.push_back(item); 
}
```

When I run the code, it only calls `void AddItem(Item* item)`, which makes sense because that's what's passed into the previous function, but since the object being passed is held in a `vector<Item*>` I can't pass it as anything else. Is there a way to detect the subclass of the object being passed and call the correct overload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [multiple dispatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1749534/multiple-dispatch-in-c).  Since the determination of which override is called is made at compile time based on the static type of the parameter, you'll need to call a function that can make use of the run time type of the object to then call back into the original `Player` object.

In your `Item` base class, you'll declare the base case for this function:

```
virtual void AddToPlayer(Player &player);
```

It is defined as

```
void Item::AddToPlayer(Player &player) {
    player.AddItem(*this);
}
```

This doesn't do anything different than you already have.  However, you can add an override of `AddToPlayer` to each class, whose definition is identical to the base class's given above.  Since the type of `*this` will be different in each definition, a different overload of `Player::AddItem` will be called.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this, but since I have `#include "Item.h"` in my Unit.h header, my compiler won't let me `#include "Unit.h"` in Item.h (`Player` is a subclass of `Unit`). Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: @JasonNickPorter You can forward declare a class by simply saying `class Player;` or `class Unit;` without including the header that defines the class.  Then include the header in the .cpp file when you need the details of the class.